# how to include xml in log-back.xml

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I am writing a custom spring boot starter project for logging. My logback-spring.xml become large and want to put the appenders in separate file (console-appender.xml and file-appender.xml) and want to include in the logback-spring.xml file like below. I place all the three xmls in src/main/resources folder in my custom starter project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="JSONLOGSENABLED" source="spring.logs.json.enabled" defaultValue="true" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="JSONLOGSAPPENDER" source="spring.logs.json.appender" defaultValue="console" />

    <if condition='property("JSONLOGSENABLED").equalsIgnoreCase("true")'>
        <then>

        <include file="{path to file}/console-appender.xml"/>
        <include file="{path to file}/file-appender.xml"/>
        <root level="INFO">
            <if condition='property("JSONLOGSAPPENDER").equalsIgnoreCase("file")'>
                <then>
                    <appender-ref ref="FILEJSON" />
                </then> 
            <else>
                <appender-ref ref="CONSOLEJSON" />
           </else>
           </if>
        </root>
    </then>
    </if>

    <logger
        name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

file-appender.xml

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>testFile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <!-- set immediateFlush to false for much higher logging throughput -->
    <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

But when use this starter in my spring boot application, it is not able to resolve the console and file appender files.

I have tried putting following paths :

```
 <include file="/src/main/resources/console-appender.xml"/>
 <include file="./console-appender.xml"/>
 <include resource="console-appender.xml"/>
```

How to include files properly in this case ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Logback uses Joran so you have to follow the Joran rules.
For more info see [documentation](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/the-logback-manual/en/chapter-3-configuration/configuration-file-syntax/file-inclusion.html).

Anyway this is the preferred way to do what you're looking for.
For instance I define two files, then you adapt it as you prefer.

**logback-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <include resource="console-appender.xml"/>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

---

**console-appender.xml**

```
<included>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Europe/Rome} [%mdc{id}] [%-11thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</included>
```

Please note the `<included>` tag is **mandatory**

Comment: Perfect !! Totally Missed <included> tag... Thanks